# jquery не срабатывает когда у кнопки disabled="disabled

Tags: html, jquery

у меня есть данная кнопка

```
<button type="button" title="Proceed to Checkout" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout no-checkout" disabled="disabled" onclick="window.location='<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Proceed to Checkout') ?></span></span></button>
```

у меня есть данный JS код

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.no-checkout').hover(function() {
            console.log('сработало');
        });
        console.log('загрузило');
    });
</script>
```

Мой код работает, но когда у кнопки появляется `disabled="disabled"` мой код перестает работать
Мне нужно чтобы он работал также когда у кнопки `disabled="disabled"` , как это сделать?

Comment: Почитать спецификацию, и понять что disable - отключает любую реакцию, в том числе и скрипты.
Вот почитайте https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109228/clicking-a-disabled-input-or-button/16109366

Answer (score 1):

Не бывает безвыходных ситуаций ))) Отслеживаем координаты...

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var width = $('.no-checkout').width();
        var height = $('.no-checkout').height();
        var top = $('.no-checkout').position().top;
        var left = $('.no-checkout').position().left;
        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            var X = e.pageX; // положения по оси X
            var Y = e.pageY; // положения по оси Y
            if (X >= left && X<= left+width){
                if (Y >= top && Y <=top+height){
                    console.log('сработало');
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" title="Proceed to Checkout" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout no-checkout" disabled="" onclick=""><span><span>dsfsd</span></span></button>
```